# Declaring Variables (Exact spot in memory)

Tags: c#, c++

If I have a class, is it possible to declare to instances of this class "side by side" in memory?

Additionally, would it be possible to bit shift a pointer from one to the other?

Comment: Answers for C++ and C# will be VERY different.  I'd suggest picking one.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, you can absolutely do this. Its called an **array**.

In fact, array indexing is the same as saying `*(pointerToBeginng + index)`. I'm not sure what you mean by "Bit shift a pointer" but you can certainly do pointer arithmetic to switch elements.

C# arrays are likely the same (not as sure on this) but you don't normally use pointers in C# anyways. This article ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379570(v=vs.80).aspx)) suggests that arrays in C# *are* contiguous, but thats from C# 2.0 so it *could* have changed (even though that's unlikely).

However, in C# all classes are *reference types* so an array of them is just an array of references. You still have to use the reference (basically a pointer) to access the actual object. In that sense, you can't declare two instances of a class and have them guaranteed to be "side-by-side". This normally doesn't matter since you don't use pointers in C# (you can, but you generally don't).

You *could* use a `struct` instead of a `class` to allow for a contiguous block of objects in C#. At this point, pointer arithmetic would work as in C++.

Comment: I may be wrong, but in C# (and in C++) an array of reference types (pointers in C++) means that the _references_ are contiguous in memory, not the objects themselves.

Comment: @DStanley You are absolutely right. In C++ you can statically create the objects (instead of using `new`) so they would still be accessible via pointer arithmetic. In C#, you have no such option, so you couldn't index *directly* to the object, you would have to go through its reference (like you always have to anyways).

Comment: Although in C#, you can make your own structs, which are value types.

Comment: @chris true, he said class, but a `struct` would be a good way to get around this limitation.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, True, I'm used to equating class with struct when written in English. I'm not sure if C# people ever refer to structs as classes in English descriptions.

Comment: @chris Unlike C++, C# strcts are very different from classes, so most C# people don't mix the two. When they do, its normally a mistake or a new programmer.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, Ah, okay. I know the difference is much larger than in C++, and in C++, it is pretty common to say class in place of struct, so I guess it's probably a good thing that doesn't scale.